# Positioning of my drop-down divs

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am having the hardest time controlling where my drop-downs show up! I have gone through the css and made changes but for some reason they don't seem to reflect. Could someone possibly see anything I am missing?

If you hover over the tabs "contact us" and "help desk" on the link below you will see what I mean.

http://krontechnology.com/dev/index_new.html

**Here is the css for the dropdowns:**

```
.chromestyle{
font-weight: bold;
}

.chromestyle:after{ /*Add margin between menu and rest of content in Firefox*/
content: "."; 
display: block; 
height: 0; 
clear: both; 
visibility: hidden;
}

.chromestyle ul{
border: 1px solid #BBB;
width: 800px;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 16px;
padding-right: 0;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0;
background-color: #000000;
height: 32px;
}

.chromestyle ul li{
display: inline;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.chromestyle ul li a{
color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 0;
text-decoration: none;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-top: 12px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-color: #666666;
}

.chromestyle ul li a:hover, .chromestyle ul li a.selected{ /*script dynamically adds a
class of "selected" to the current active menu item*/
}

/* ######### Style for Drop Down Menu ######### */

.dropmenudiv{
position:absolute;
border: 1px solid #BBB; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
border-bottom-width: 0;
font:normal 12px Verdana;
line-height:18px;
z-index:100;
background-color: white;
width: 150px;
visibility: hidden;
}


.dropmenudiv a{
width: auto;
display: block;
text-indent: 3px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
padding: 2px 0;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}

* html .dropmenudiv a{ /*IE only hack*/
width: 100%;
}

.dropmenudiv a:hover{ /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

**Here is the html code for the page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="images/chromestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="chromejs/chrome.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="flash">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash
/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="800" height="237" title="SAP Specialists">
<param name="movie" value="SAP.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<embed src="SAP.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com
/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800" height="237">
/embed>
</object>
</div>
<div id="dropmenu">
<div class="chromestyle" id="chromemenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">ABOUT US  </a></li>
<li><a href="#">THE TEAM </a></li>
<li><a href="#">POSITIONS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">QUICK FACTS </a></li>
<li><a href="#">TESTIMONIALS </a></li>  
<li><a href="#">PARTNERS </a></li>  
<li><a href="#" rel="dropmenu1">CONTACT US </a></li>    
<li><a href="#">CASE STUDIES </a></li>  
<li><a href="#" rel="dropmenu2">HELP DESK</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!--1st drop down menu -->                                                   
<div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenudiv">
<a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Locations</a>
<a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">Register</a></div>


<!--2nd drop down menu -->                                                
<div id="dropmenu2" class="dropmenudiv" style="width: 150px;">
<a href="http://www.cnn.com/">Collateral</a></div>

<!--3rd drop down menu -->
<script type="text/javascript">

cssdropdown.startchrome("chromemenu")

</script>
</div>

<div id="main"></div>
<div id="rr"><img src="images/RR-teaser.png" width="255" height="168" /></div>
<div id="testimonials"><img src="images/Testimonials-bknd.png" width="258" height="168" 
/></div>
<div id="dod"><img src="images/DoD-teaser.png" width="255" height="168" /></div>
<div id="footer">Copyright 
2009 Kr&ouml;ntechnology.com &nbsp;I &nbsp;Contact Webmaster</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: do you want to have a dropdown or not?
i think it may be bcoz of position:absolute!
i am running this in IE6, and i can see the dropdown to extreme right!

Answer (score 3):

Three things you're doing wrong:

1. Using absolute positioning without a relative parent
2. Using Javascript to change the position values
3. Not really wrong per se, but you lose semantics because the dropdowns are not part of the menu. They're not associated with their parent items.

For #1, you should set the menu (`#dropmenu`) to `position:relative`. Then all absolutely positioned children will be positioned relative to the top left of that element. This means you can put `top: 0; left: 500px` on the drop down* and it will always appear in the same place. (The 500 value is just a guess but since your design is fixed with, it will be a constant value.)

For #2, this means you don't need to use Javascript to reposition the elements, just turn the visibility on and off.

For #3, I would also suggest that you make the dropdowns children of the menu itself, rather than siblings. This is more semantic and screenreaders then know the relationship between the menu items. You could use HTML similar to this:

```
<ul class="menu-level1">
  <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contact Us</a>
    <ul class="menu-level2">
      <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Case Studies</a></li>
</ul>
```

You would set `position: relative` on `.menu-level1` and `position: absolute` on `.menu-level2`.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't take into account the offsetLeft of your #wrap div.

make the change to your cssdropdown file.

```
cssdropdown.dropit = function(obj, e, dropmenuID){
    if (this.dropmenuobj!=null) //hide previous menu
        this.hidemenu() //hide menu
    this.clearhidemenu()
    this.dropmenuobj=document.getElementById(dropmenuID) //reference drop down menu
    this.asscmenuitem=obj //reference associated menu item
    this.showmenu(this.dropmenuobj, e)
    this.dropmenuobj.x=this.getposOffset(obj, "left")
    this.dropmenuobj.y=this.getposOffset(obj, "top")
        // <<<<<< BEGIN CHANGE (notice the "- document.getElementById('wrap').offsetLeft")
    this.dropmenuobj.style.left=(this.dropmenuobj.x-this.clearbrowseredge(obj, "rightedge")-document.getElementById('wrap').offsetLeft)+"px"
        // <<<<<< END CHANGE
    this.dropmenuobj.style.top=this.dropmenuobj.y-this.clearbrowseredge(obj, "bottomedge")+obj.offsetHeight+1+"px"
    this.positionshim() //call iframe shim function
}
```